# Why is this basic JavaScript event not working?

Tags: javascript, events

Just trying to have some fun with my current, very limited, knowledge of JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/pDMq9/

Why isnt this working? What have I done wrong?

**HTML**

```
<body>

<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button" />

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;

var p = document.getElementById("button");

function mousedown() {
    if (p.mousedown) {
        alert(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? All you are doing is setting some variables and declaring a function. You never *call* that function.

Comment: You're never calling that event

Comment: You never actually bind to the `onmousedown` event.  You just make a function called `mousedown`.

Comment: How does the button click know to run `mousedown()`?

Comment: Here's a hint; you need to do SOMETHING with that mousedown function to "register" it.  You've declared a function that will do something when p is clicked, but what do you have to do to MAKE that "count?"

Answer (score 8):

1. You try to get values from the event outside the `mousedown` function (i.e. before the event exists)
2. You never assign the `mousedown` function as an event handler
3. You don't accept any arguments to the  `mousedown` function
4. You test for a `mousedown` *property* inside the `mousedown` function for no apparent reason
5. You pass multiple arguments to `alert`

So to fix it:

```
function mousedownHandler(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    alert(x + ", " + y);
}

var p = document.getElementById("button");
p.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedownHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the `click` or `mousedown` event to the element. Inside the function you can get the event and retrieve `clientX` and `clientY` from that.

**JavaScript**

```
var p = document.getElementById("button");

p.onclick = function mousedown(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    alert(x + ' ' + y);
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/8gzMj/

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer! Makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

1. `e` is not a global variable. Usually `e` is the event associated to an event handler:

   ```
          function mousedownHandler(e)
          {
              //manage the event
              console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
          }
   ```
2. an event handler should be bind to the corresponding event:

   ```
     var p = document.getElementById("button");
     p.onmousedown = mousedownHandler;
   ```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GM7nP/2/) is a running fork of your example in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to attach an event to the element. Then you need to pass in 'e' or the event. Then you can read it's properties.

```
var p = document.getElementById("button");

p.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

function mousedown(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;

    alert(x, y);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSUfL/

Answer (score -1):

you don't call the function, you must use this

```
  <body>

 <input type="button" value="Click me" id="button" onClick="mousedown()" />

 </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mousedown(e) {
            var x = e.clientX;
            var y = e.clientY;
            alert(x + "\n" + y);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" id="button" onmousedown="mousedown(event);" />
        <!-- alternatively -->
        <button id="button2" onmousedown="mousedown(event)">Click me</button>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```